# Add post row action to call a function without rendering WP-Admin UI

Tags: wordpress

I am using the following code to add a new link to the post row actions.

```
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'pdf_row_actions', 10, 2 );
function pdf_row_actions( $actions, WP_Post $post ) {
    if ( $post->post_type == 'carte' ) {
      $url = admin_url('admin.php?page=generate_pdf_carte&id='.$post->ID);
      $actions['generate-pdf'] = '<a href="'.$url.'" title="PDF generieren" rel="permalink">PDF herunterladen</a>';
    }

    return $actions;
}

function generate_pdf_carte(){

  $options = new Options();
  $options->set('tempDir', 'tmp');
  $dompdf = new Dompdf($options);

  $dompdf->loadHtmlFile('http://localhost/xxx/output.php');

  // (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
  $dompdf->setPaper('A4');
  $dompdf->render();
  $dompdf->stream();
}
```

When I click this link I get this message: **Unable to stream pdf: headers already sent**

How can I add a URL to this generate_pdf_carte() function without rendering the admin UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use admin_init hook for contents that require setting headers.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'maybe_generate_pdf_carte' );   
function maybe_generate_pdf_carte() {  
    if ( isset( $_GET['page'], $_GET['id'] ) && $_GET['page'] == 'generate_pdf_carte' && (int)$_GET['id'] )
        generate_pdf_carte();
}
```